# Change an If statement to a function in Java

Tags: java, function, if-statement, methods

I'm new to programming and I'm learning about functions in Java language.

There are to functions, one describing the growth of rabbits and another one describing the growth of foxes. In both functions, there is a `if` statement to avoid that `nbRabbits` or `nbFoxex` reach a negative number.

```
public static double calculateRabbits(double rabbits, double foxes, double attackRate) {

        for (int i = 0; i < Duration; ++i){
            rabbits = nbRabbits;
            nbRabbits *= (1.0 + GROWTH_RATE_RABBITS - attackRate * nbFoxes );

            **if (nbRabbits < 0.0){
                nbRabbits = 0.0;
            }**
        }

        return nbRabbits;   
    }

public static double calculateFoxes(double rabbits, double foxes, double attackRate) {

        for (int i = 0; i < Duration; ++i){
            nbFoxes *= (1.0 + ATTACK_RATE_INIT * rabbits * GROWTH_RATE_FOXES - MORTALITY_RATE);

            **if (nbFoxes < 0.0){
            nbFoxes = 0.0;
             }** 

        }

        return nbFoxes;
    }
```

My question is: how can I change this `if` to another function? I want to avoid the copy and paste of the `if`.

Comment: You want to create a new function for two lines?

Comment: Use `while` instead of `if`? I don't understand the problem. By the way, from a real world perspective, the type `double` makes no sense for number of animals.

Comment: Functions are known as methods in java

Comment: Actually I don't want to create a method for just two lines. My professor wants... haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to help you. First, I think that you shouldn't use `double` for that kind of variable. Instead, use `int`.

```
int rabbit;
int foxes;
```

To answer your question, you can do something like this:

```
public double nonZero(double v)
{
  double value = 0.0;

  /*If v is less than 0 then return 0*/
  if (v < 0.0) {
   value = 0.0;
  }

  /*If v is greater than cero return v*/
  else
  {
    value = v;
  }
  return value; 
}
```

If you create a method like this, you can call the method instead of the if and do something like:

```
nbRabbits = nonZero(nbRabbits);
nbFoxes = nonZero(nbFoxes);
```

to avoid a negative number.

Answer (score 6):

Avoiding copy-paste is definitely a good goal. But there's an even better  solution than writing a function to replace it - using a function that somebody else has already written. In this case, [`java.util.Math#max`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max-double-double-). E.g.:

```
nFoxes = Math.max(nFoxes, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I'd take a completely different approach and use a helper function:

```
private static int calculateAnimals(int ours, int other, double growth_rate, double factor) {
    int result = ours;
    for (int i = 0; i < Duration; ++i) {
        result *= (1.0 + growth_rate + factor * other);
        if (result < 0.0) {
            result = 0.0;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public static int calculateFoxes(double rabbits, double foxes, double attackRate) {
    return calculateAnimals(foxes, rabbits, -MORTALITY_RATE, ATTACK_RATE_INIT * GROWTH_RATE_FOXES);
}

public static int calculateRabbits(double rabbits, double foxes, double attackRate) {
    return calculateAnimals(rabbits, foxes, GROWTH_RATE_RABBITS, -attackRate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way; create a single method and return the value if it is greater than zero, otherwise set it to zero. With the method.

```
public static double calculateRabbits(double rabbits, double foxes, double attackRate) {
            for (int i = 0; i < Duration; ++i){

                rabbits = numberOfRabbits(nbRabbits);
                nbRabbits *= (1.0 + GROWTH_RATE_RABBITS - attackRate * nbFoxes );  
            return nbRabbits;   
        }
    public static double mustNotBeZero(double numberOfRabbits){
             if(numberOfRabbits<0){
                 numberOfRabbits=0.0;
               }
            else
               return numberOfRabbits;
    }
```